# Sticky Note in Redhat 5

Tags: software-rec, rhel-5, sticky-notes

Does anyone know if there is a "sticky note" application for Rhel5? In Ubuntu, there is Xpad and Tomboy, but I couldn't see an rpm version for this. I tried to download the tarball for Tomboy but it was giving this error:

```
configure: error: gnome-doc-utils >= 0.17.3 not found
```

Comment: You can get the tarball for the package missing here http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-doc-utils/0.17/

Comment: I installed the 0.17.5 version and removed the older gnome-doc-utils that was installed via rpm. And yet it still cannot find the gnome-doc-utils. I think it is a path issue but I don't know how to tell configure to look for the path and I don't even know where gnome-doc-utils was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Tomboy requires Mono, which AFAIK RHEL does not ship.  You might want to take a look at Gnote, which provides similar functionality but does not require Mono.

Gnote is available in the RepoForge (formerly RPMForge) third-party repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  First, [enable that repository](http://repoforge.org/use/) and then you can install Gnote with the following command:

```
yum install gnote
```

Unfortuntately, they don't build it for RHEL5, but you can rebuild an RPM using the source RPM (SRPM).  To do that, first you need to [download the SRPM](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/gnote/gnote-0.7.2-0.1.rf.src.rpm).  Then, tell YUM to install `rpmbuild` if you don't already have it, by running this as `root`:

```
yum install rpmbuild
```

Next, install all dependencies needed to build it, again as `root`:

```
yum-builddep gnote-0.7.2-0.1.rf.src.rpm
```

Now you can rebuild the package using this command, which you *should not* run as `root`:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild gnote-0.7.2-0.1.rf.src.rpm
```

That will build and drop an RPM in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/<arch>`, where `<arch>` is `i386` or `x86_64` depending on whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system installed.  All you have to do then is install it, as `root` this time:

```
rpm -ivh gnote-0.7.2-0.1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Comment: interesting. I 'enabled' the rpmforge repository and yet it still could not find the gnote rpm.

Comment: Ugh.  Looks like they only built it for RHEL6.  I'll post instructions on how to rebuild it from the SRPM.

Comment: when I run this: yum-builddep gnote-0.7.2-0.1.rf.src.rpm, it complained that Error: No Package found for dbus-c++-devel. And it looks like this package is also only available for rhel6. Hmm.

Comment: They don't call it *dependency hell* for nothing.  ;-)  Rebuild `dbus-c++` from the [RHEL6 SRPM](http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Client/en/os/SRPMS/dbus-c++-0.5.0-0.10.20090203git13281b3.1.el6.src.rpm) following the above instructions.  That SRPM will build both the `dbus-c++-devel` package needed to build `gnote` and the `dbus-c++` library package needed to actually run it.  Go ahead and install both in the last step.  Then, try building `gnote` again.  (P.S. I double-checked the spec files and everything else seems fairly vanilla, so you shouldn't have any more surprises.  :-)

Comment: @Carmen you don't suggest an edit on an answer to add clarifying information about what happened. You either edit your question, or leave the info in comments.

Comment: oops, I didn't mean to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using KDE, *[KNotes](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/knotes/)* is what you need.

> KNotes is a program that lets you
>   write the computer equivalent of
>   sticky notes. The notes are saved
>   automatically when you exit the
>   program, and they display when you
>   open the program.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, I am using gnome. But is there a way to install this application in gnome?

Comment: Yes, there is. However installing a KDE app on gnome will require many dependencies, thus I don't recommend it. The app you're looking for is Gnote than, mentioned in @Patches answer below.